# Fixed-length regex lookbehind complains of variable-length lookbehind

Tags: php, regex

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
$str = 'a,b,c,d';
return preg_split('/(?<![^\\\\][\\\\]),/', $str);
```

As you can see, the regexp being used here is:

```
/(?<![^\\][\\]),/
```

Which is a simple fixed-length negative lookbehind for "preceded by something that isn't a backslash, then something that is!".

This regex works just fine on http://www.phpliveregex.com

But when I go and actually attempt to run the above code, I am spat back the error:

```
Warning:  preg_split() [function.preg-split]: Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 13
```

To make matters worse, a fellow programmer tested the code on his 5.4.24 PHP server, and it worked fine.

This leads me to believe that my issues are related to the configuration of my server, which I have very little control over. I am told that my PHP version if 5.2.*

Are there any workarounds/alternatives to preg_replace() that might not have this issue?

Comment: When ran the code indeed works fine and splits the results.

Comment: Probably not real 5.2. It works for me, and you can see in which versions it fails [here](http://3v4l.org/PlBUB) (fails in 4.3.0 - 4.4.4, 5.0.0 - 5.1.6). Be aware you are running an _ancient_ PHP version.

Comment: @Wrikken Oh my, never knew about the tool. It's wonderful. )

Comment: @Wrikken Yeah, I am beginning to suspect you are correct. Someone has suggested that it might be 5.2 php, but with an outdated pcrelib. Are there any workarounds for doing this kind of thing in older pcrelib versions, or am I just going to have to write a char-by-char parsing function for this and be done with it?

Comment: You can use [`'/(?<!(?<!\\\\)\\\\),/'`](http://3v4l.org/AtJWb), which succeeds in all versions (note: fixed logical error in previous version of this comment).

Comment: @raina77ow: it is an extremely awesome and useful site indeed ;)

Comment: However, does this split the string `a\\\,b` as intended? (or: `'a\\\\\\,b'` with escaped quotes).

Comment: @raina77ow: yeah, saw that, you are probably looking at a previous incarnation of the comment with a `?<! ?<=` combo...

Comment: FWIW: I'd favor matching over splitting to get a reliable behavior independent of the number of \'s in there: `preg_match_all('/(?:[^\\\\,]|\\\\.)+/u',$str,$matches);` (the old 'not an escape or delimiter, or an escape directly followed by anything you like - sequence')

Comment: @Wrikken: What a useful code tester!

Comment: @Wrikken Well, yes, `preg_match_all` seems to be the most appropriate here. The only caveat (that took me quite a long time to fix) is the trailing slashes. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the bug fixed in PCRE 6.7. Quoting [**the changelog**](http://www.pcre.org/changelog.txt):

> A negated single-character class was not being recognized as
>   fixed-length in lookbehind assertions such as `(?<=[^f])`, leading to an
>   incorrect compile error `"lookbehind assertion is not fixed length"`

PCRE 6.7 was introduced in [**PHP 5.2.0**](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.2.0), in Nov 2006. As you still have this bug, it means it's not still there at your server - so for a preg-split based workaround you have to use a pattern without a negative character class. For example:

```
$patt = '/(?<!(?<!\\\\)\\\\),/';
// or...
$patt = '/(?<![\x00-\x5b\x5d-\xFF]\x5c),/';
```

---

However, I find the whole approach a bit weird: what if `,` symbol is preceded by exactly three backslashes? Or five? Or any odd number of them? The comma in this case should be considered 'escaped', but obviously you cannot create a lookbehind expression of variable length to cover these cases.

On the second thought, one can use `preg_match_all` instead, with a common alternation trick to cover the escaped symbols:

```
$str = 'e ,a\\,b\\\\,c\\\\\\,d\\\\';
preg_match_all('/(?:[^\\\\,]|\\\\(?:.|$))+/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

[**Demo**](http://3v4l.org/VdkB0).

*I really think I covered all the issues here, those trailing slashes were a killer )*

Comment: Thank you very much! A well put together, fully informative answer. Exactly the kind of content SO needs :)

Answer (score 1):

Way to avoid the negated character class *(I write `\x5c` instead of a lot of backslashes to be more clear)*

```
$result = preg_split('/(?<!(?!\x5c).\x5c),/s', $str);
```

About the approach itself:

If you are trying to split on comma that are not escaped, you are in the wrong way with a lookbehind since you can't check and undefined number of backslash before the comma. You have several possibilities to solve this problem:

```
$result = preg_split('/(?:[^\x5c]|\A)(?:\x5c.)*\K,/s', $str);
```

or

```
$result = preg_split('/(?<!\x5c)(?:\x5c.)*\K,/s', $str);
```

or for PHP > 5.2.4

```
$result = preg_split('/\x5c{2}(*SKIP)(?!)|(?<!\x5c),/s', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using an older php version since I your error rises on **PHP 5.1.6** or lower.

You can check a **[non working demo here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/252b1806c7902cb4813d86c3daf884cdc7741823)**

[image]

On the other hand it works for **PHP 5.2.16** or higher:

**[Working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/252b1806c7902cb4813d86c3daf884cdc7741823)**

[image]